# Spark batch duration is showing higher than actual execution time

Tags: performance, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am running Spark Streaming job and has been struggling to get the throughput right. Below are some of the details about the job

```
Batch window: 30 seconds
Processing 5 kafka topic with 20 partition each
Kafka per message size 100 to 300 bytes
10 executor 3GB memory each
A driver with 4GB nmemory
Backpressure is enabled
Expected throughput 4000 - 6000 messages/seconds
Spark job is writing data to flume and Axibase socket
```

I am observing that Processing time of each batch is exceeding 30 seconds(34, 35 36 seconds or more..) but when i look into each batch the duration shows 15 to 20 seconds. 
Not sure what causing this miss-match and since the overall batch processing time is higher than batch window. the jobs are getting queued up .

Would appreciate any help in identifying the issue here. Thanks in advance

Comment: We can't help without knowing more about how your graph is defined.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the Streaming tab in the Spark UI?

Comment: I'm with the Axibase dev team. Let us know via http://axibase.com/feedback/ if tech support is required on this issue.